# Android SQLite database corrupted when pulling with ADB

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a big problem with the SQLite database on Android. In a file DatabaseContra.java I have

```
public static class HeartRateEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "heart_rate_readings";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SESSION_ID = "session_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SENSOR_ID= "sensor_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_NANO = "timestamp_nano";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_MILLI = "timestamp_milli";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_HR = "heart_rate";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RR = "rr_interval";
}
```

In a DatabaseHelper class inheriting from SQLiteOpenHelper I have the create statement for the table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_HEART_RATE_READINGS =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SESSION_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SENSOR_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_NANO + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_MILLI + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_HR + " INTEGER," +
                DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RR + " INTEGER);";
```

In the `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` method I'm creating the table `db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HEART_RATE_READINGS);`

No I try to insert every second one row through

```
SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.context);
SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SESSION_ID, MainActivity.sessionDbID);
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SENSOR_ID, MainActivity.polarDbID);
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_NANO, timeNano);
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP_MILLI, timeMilli);
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_HR, hr);
contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RR, rr[i]);
db.insert(DatabaseContract.HeartRateEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

The database is used in a service but I'm using the context of the MainActivity (which I have stored in a static variable there). I'm using it in a service but I just use the context of the MainActivity. I'm leaving the connection open to the database and only close it at the very end. I also only use one connection to the database.

I'm not getting any error message while execution. But then I'm pulling the database from my PC with

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.example cat /data/data/com.example/databases/sensors.db" > C:\Users\myName\Desktop\sensors.db
```

When I now open the database with SQLiteStudio I'm getting the following error message when I want to access the table:

> Could not load data for table heart_rate_readings. Error details:
>   Error while executing SQL query on database 'sensors': database disk
>   image is malformed

What could the error be? I'm completely stuck and have no clue what it could be. I'm using Android 5.1.

I have also defined other tables (user information etc.). These table work (but there I only enter records once and not every second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for pulling the database from the device:

```
adb -d pull /data/data/com.example/databases/sensors.db
```

If you can't access the database like this, but `run-as` works for you, then copy the database to publicly accessible location (e.g. `/`) and then use `pull`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have no rooted tablet, so I think this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But why does my command not work? It uses adb too. adb -d shell "run-as com.example cat /data/data/com.example/databases/sensors.db" > C:\Users\myName\Desktop\sensors.db

Comment: @machinery, I don't know for sure. I guess that there are two possible issues: 1) `cat` corrupts the database 2) `adb shell` corrupts the database

Comment: @machinery, you can try something like this: `adb -d shell "run-as com.example cat /data/data/com.example/databases/sensors.db > /sensors.db"` and then `adb -d pull /sensors.db`. If this works, then the problem is in transfer of database file through `adb shell`. If not, then `cat` is probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. If cat is the problem, how could I solve it? Because I need cat for copying file to accessible location. Second, with the adb pull command you provided, is there also a possibility to provide the storage location on the PC (e.g. C:\sensors.db)?

Comment: Could also be something wrong with my Java code? But I think when something would be wrong, I should get SQL errors during runtime (which I don't get).

Comment: It seems that adb exec-out run-as package.name cat databases/file > file works. So probably shell caused the problem.